# jquery ajax not working with firefox

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, firefox

I'm trying to send a simple request (no CGI parameters) to a URL and have the server return a complex (about 50k-byte) object.  Everything seems to work fine until the reply comes back and the .ajax.error() function gets called.  The XHRs (jqXHR and return value from $.ajax() don't give anything useful, other that to say there is an error (see #2).

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery-UI 1.10.3
Sorry, the URLs are munged for security.  sldn.com is not the real domain, and the links
below will not work (other than the reference to the JQ ajax page).

What I've tried so far:

1. Point a browser at https://server.sldn.com:9007/bin/feed_status/feed_status.cgi and yes, I get an ajax value sent back.
2. Using Live http headers, verify that the content-type is not causing a conflict (see #1 below)
3. Make sure that the acceptable JSON rules under the .ajax documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/.  Tags and values have to be double-quoted and no single backslashes (they have to be doubled up).  It would take work and probably render the ajax useless if I were to munge it in a show-able way.
4. Ran DNS lookups on the source and destination server to check whether this is really local or not.  "Local" requires that the scheme (https), server (call it server.sldn.com) and ports match.  Scheme and server match, I'm not sure about how ports are matched up.
5. Tried setting localDomain to true, false, and default.  Defaults to false and setting it to true causes the .ajax function to error out before the request is sent.
6. Take the code generated by the .cgi out of the web browser and paste it into test_script().  Get a return value, eval() it and make sure JS is happy with the text.  It is.  I can browse the resulting object in firebug.
7. Check the "this" value when inside get_feed_status_json_error().  The best it gives is #2 below.

## 1

```
https:server.sldn.com:9007/bin/feed_status/feed_status.cgi

GET /bin/feed_status/feed_status.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: server.sldn.com:9007
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: https:server.sldn.com:9007/feed_status/feed_status.html
Origin: https:server.sldn.com:9007
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 20:19:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat)
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

## 2

```
Results passed to get_feed_status_json_error()
0 Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error", more...}
  readyState    0
  responseText  ""
  status    0
  statusText    "error"

1 "error"
2 ""


this:
accepts             Object { *="*/*", text="text/plain", html="text/html", more...}
async               true
contentType         "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
contents            Object { xml=RegExp, html=RegExp, json=RegExp, more...}
converters          Object { text html=true, * text=String(), text json=function(), more...}
crossDomain         true
dataType            "json"
dataTypes           ["text", "json"]
flatOptions         Object { url=true, context=true}
global              true
hasContent          false
isLocal             false
jsonp               "callback"
processData         true
responseFields      Object { xml="responseXML", text="responseText"}
type                "GET"
url                 "https://server.sldn..._status/feed_status.cgi"
error               function()
jsonpCallback       function()
success             function()
xhr                 createStandardXHR()
```

## 3

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $( "#DatePicker" ).datepicker();

  $("#debug_info_checkbox").prop("checked", false);
  $("#debug_info_text").hide();

  get_feed_status_json();

});

// This typically runs in the 7-10 second range.
function get_feed_status_json() {

var x =test_script();

$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
            url: "https://server.sldn.com:9007/bin/feed_status/feed_status.cgi",
       dataType: "json",
        success:  get_feed_status_json_success,
          error:  get_feed_status_json_error,
  });

}
var get_feed_status_json_success =
function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  alert("Got data!\\n" + textStatus);
  return data;
};

var get_feed_status_json_error   =
function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert("Got error:  " + jqXHR.status);
};



function test_script() {
  return '{"feeds":{"Big wad of json here"}';
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You added the `firefox` tag ; does the request work with other browsers ? You get HTTP 200 but the error handler is fired, as if the JSON couldn't be parsed, this might be because you are getting back `chunked` JSON. Maybe you could ask for `text` instead and see how it looks.

Comment: Well, gee.  I'm not used to debugging with IE, but the IE debugger is very much improved since I tried it last!  Ok, so IE caught a dangling comma, and now it did throw a "No Transport" error immediately.  After Googling that and finding a suggestion to add

   jQuery.support.cors = true;

IE was happy, but FF behaves just the same.

Comment: I did try sending it via text.  The headers changed accordingly, but I got a 200 just the same.

Comment: Turns out, IE likes it in "quirks mode", but not in "standards" mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough.  When I opened the web page in a browser, I typed just "server" instead of "server.sldn.com" in the address bar and let the default DNS suffix find it.

So, to avoid my particular version of pain in using jquery.ajax, be sure your browser has a FQDN or else it has a problem with cross origin resource sharing (CORS).  You may want to make your web site redirect to the FQDN or something like that.